# Authentication to Klocwork from another application

Tags: authentication, ldap, klocwork

I'm trying to implement integration between two systems, one of them being Klocwork. For now the other system would only retrieve data from Klocwork and work with them further. For retrieving of the data I want to use WEB API. However I encountered problem with the authentication.

Authentication to KW is setup through LDAP. According to documentation I will have to authenticate before I can actually retrieve the data from KW on the side of the other system.

Is there a possibility to authenticate through WEB API or is it possible only through the use of kwauth?
If it is possible only through kwauth is there some easier way to automate the process of authentication from some external system or do I have to manually authenticate each person individually through command and save the token in the other system for the later use?

Thanks a lot for any help,

Jakub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to authenticate with the WebAPI besides using the ltoken. You will have to use `kwauth` to authenticate just once for the LDAP user account you are using to access the WebAPI.  This will create an 'ltoken' file for authenticating with the Klocwork server which can be used for the WebAPI requests.

http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/current/Klocwork_Insight_Web_API_cookbook#Authentication

I would just use one specific LDAP account, and ltoken, for all of the WebAPI requests, unless that doesn't work for your scenario.  There should be no need to manually run `kwauth` for every user.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to know. Well in my case it would not be per user but per some superuser which would be one for each project. But anyway thank you very much I wanted to be sure that there is not anything that I do not see.